# Restoring Hive ORC table after changing source location?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

Assume you have two external Hive ORC tables. Both of them have the same schema with same datatypes, same partitions and same buckets.

I'm trying to drop table A and set the location of table B to table A's source location. I've tried both:

```
alter tableB set location "hdfs://.../tableA"
```

and

```
msck repair table B
```

without luck.

Comment: Did you try to set partitions locations as well?

Comment: To emphasize the point raised by @leftjoin, for a partitioned table, the table-level "location" is just the **default root dir for future partitions**. Existing partitions have their own "location" registered in the metastore database. You have to ALTER them all, one by one.

Comment: Or, you may try to *(1)* drop all partitions from table B *(2)* change "location" for table B *(3)* run `MSCK repair` to auto-detect the sub-directories. In that order.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are external tables when you drop them the files will still remain. So all you should have to do is drop table A and table b. Then recreate table b using the file location of table A.

```
drop tableA;
drop tableB;
create external table if not exists tableB (
....your existing DDL
)
location 'tableA path';
```